# Codeigniter - Is it possible to add multiple dynamic datas to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having a trouble on what ways will i do, when i change this $this->load->view('profile',['getPlacetype'=>$getPlacetype],$custom_errors ); to this
$this->load->view('profile',['getPlacetype'=>$getPlacetype],$custom_errors );
there will be no undefined index but the selection data will be none

**profilecon**

```
    public function index(){

    $this->load->model('Placetype');
    $getPlacetype = $this->Placetype->getPlacetype();


    if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header("Location: ".base_url()."index.php/login_con/login");
        die();

    }
    $custom_errors["nadate"] = false;
    if (isset($_POST['profile'])) {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobilenum', 'Mobile Number', 
     'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('homeadd', 'Home Address', 
     'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('startdate', 'Start Date', 
     'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('enddate', 'End Date', 
     'required');

        $custom_errors["nadate"] = ($this->verifydate($_POST["startdate"], 
      $_POST["enddate"]) < 3 ? false : true);


        //if form validation true
         if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE && $this- 
        >verifydate($_POST["startdate"], $_POST["enddate"]) < 3) {
        $data = array(
                'username' => $this->session->userdata("username"),
                'mobilenum' => $_POST['mobilenum'],
                'homeadd' => $_POST['homeadd'],
                'startdate' => $_POST['startdate'],
                'enddate' => $_POST['enddate'],
            );

            $_SESSION["profile_data"] = $data;
            redirect("shopping_cart","refresh");
          }

          }

        $this->load->view('profile',     
        ['getPlacetype'=>$getPlacetype],$custom_errors );


            }
```

**placetype_model**

```
  <?php


  class Placetype extends CI_MODEL{


public function getPlacetype(){
$query = $this->db->get('placetype');
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
}
}



}
```

**profile_view**

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="place_type">City/Province</label>
        <select name="place_type">
        <option value="place_type">-Please Select One-</option>
        <?php if(count($getPlacetype)):?>
        <?php foreach($getPlacetype as $getplacetype):?>
        <option value=
        <?php echo $getplacetype->place_id;?>>
       <?php echo $getplacetype->place_type;?> 
       <?php echo $getplacetype->place_price;?><span> PHP Shipping 
       Fee</span>
       </option>

      <?php endforeach;?>
       <?php else:?>
       <?php endif;?>
         </select>
       </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" 
      name="profile">Proceed</button>
      </div>
      </form>

     </div>
```

Comment: And the question is? What errors are you facing to? What is expected results? ...?

Comment: Is there other way to add multiple dynamic datas to view, My facing errors are the my $custom_errors  variables becomes undefined index.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to send lots of data to a view. The thing to understand is how the array you send to the view is used. Put simply, each `key` in the array will be the name of a `variable` in the view. The array must be an associative array.

With that in mind

```
//this line
$getPlacetype = $this->Placetype->getPlacetype();
// should be changed to this
$view_data['getPlacetype'] = $this->Placetype->getPlacetype();
```

and then

```
$custom_errors["nadate"] = ($this->verifydate($_POST["startdate"],
// changed to
$nadate = ($this->verifydate($_POST["startdate"],
                        $_POST["enddate"]) < 3 ? false : true);
```

You can delete the line

```
$custom_errors["nadate"] = false;
```

Change this

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE && 
   $this->verifydate($_POST["startdate"], $_POST["enddate"]) < 3) {
```

to

```
if($nadate === TRUE && $this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
```

If the above block is not executed then create an error message and load the view

```
$view_data['custom_errors'] = "Start and End dates were wrong";
$this->load->view('profile', $view_data);
```

The relevant part of the view could be done like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="place_type">City/Province</label>
    <select name="place_type">
        <option value="place_type">-Please Select One-</option>
        <?php
        if(count($getPlacetype)) :
            foreach ($getPlacetype as $getplacetype):
                ?>
                <option value=<?php echo $getplacetype->place_id; ?>>
                    <?php
                    echo $getplacetype->place_type;
                    echo $getplacetype->place_price;
                    ?>
                <span> PHP Shipping Fee</span>
                </option>

                <?php
            endforeach;
            else:
               echo isset($custom_errors) ? $custom_errors : NULL;
            endif;
            ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Hope this demonstrates how to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this:define array blank.

```
   public function index(){
  $data = array();
```

//here you can use $data and like firstArray you can pass in your view page.you can use multiple array like this and pass then in view.

```
$data['firstArray']=get data;
$data['secondArray']=get data;
 $this->load->view(''profile', $data);
}
```